# eval command onto other buffer in Emacs 

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, viper-mode

I have a broken meta key and am trying to do M-x viper-mode onto an org file.

I want elisp to run (viper-mode) onto the example.org file from the *scratch* buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lisp, call `set-buffer` to switch to a different buffer for editing operations (this doesn't affect what buffer the user interacts with).

```
(save-excursion
  (set-buffer "example.org")
  (viper-mode))
```

The `save-excursion` form executes its arguments, then returns to the originally current buffer. Here, you could actually use `progn` instead, because returning to the toplevel restores the current buffer. But you need to group the two function calls anyway, and `save-excursion` is a good habit to get into.

But note that your problem is that your Meta key doesn't work, you can type <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> instead of <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (and likewise for any other `M-key` combination).